# How to model multiple "uses" (e.g. weapon) for usable-inventory/object/items (e.g. katana) within a relational database

Tags: database, architecture, tagging

So I'm working on expanding the uses of items over at [www.ninjawars.net](http://www.ninjawars.net), and I'm not exactly sure how to represent them flexibly in the relational database that we use.

I may be barking up the wrong tree, so feel free to make suggestions in other directions, but currently I'm thinking that each item should have relational "tags".

For example, a Katana is currently a row in the "items" database.  To make it into a weapon, and a holdable thing, I was thinking that I would have a database of "traits", and a item_traits table that connects the two.

```
// Objects and their basic data

item_id | item | material | etc
1 | Naginata | steel | etc


// Things that objects can do

trait_id | trait
1 | weapon
2 | holdable

// How those objects do those things, e.g. powerfully, weakly, while on fire

_item_id | _trait_id | item_trait_data
1 | 1 | damage: 5, damage_type: sharp, whatever, etc
```

I'm not really sure how to model the extra data that results (e.g. the damage that a sword will do, the damage_type, etc).

I'm also not especially happy that the whole of an item would be stored in more than one place, e.g. in order to create a copy of an item with a different name, like a "short sword", I would have to copy from multiple tables to create the duplicate item.

Is there a better way to lay this stuff out that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, different kinds of weapons can share common feats.
For example, "sharp" weapons can include longswords, short swords, daggers, and katanas; they all could share similar base damage, plus a few extra special things that pertain to the actual weapon individually.
Similarly, "blunt" weapons can include hammers, maces, and flails.
So I think you should introduce the concept of a "weapon type", so you don't have to copy things for each weapon type.